# Best plotting technique for dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image][image]

I am trying to visualize the following dataframe in a way that captures all information. The data frame is below

```
> d
Source: local data frame [16 x 4]
Groups: bowler, wicketKind [?]
       bowler wicketKind  wicketPlayerOut runsConceded
       (fctr)      (chr)            (chr)        (dbl)
1     SJ Harmison     bowled         DI Joyce            0
2     SJ Harmison     caught      DT Johnston            0
3     SJ Harmison     caught      WK McCallan            0
4     SJ Harmison    not-out           nobody           58
5       G Chapple    not-out           nobody           14
6     LE Plunkett    not-out           nobody           48
7      SI Mahmood     caught          JP Bray            0
8      SI Mahmood    not-out           nobody           21
9  PD Collingwood     bowled         AC Botha            0
10 PD Collingwood     caught     PG Gillespie            0
11 PD Collingwood    not-out           nobody           26
12  JWM Dalrymple    not-out           nobody           51
13  JWM Dalrymple    stumped D Langford-Smith            0
14        IR Bell     caught         AR White            0
15        IR Bell     caught       KJ O'Brien            0
16        IR Bell    not-out           nobody           39
```

I tried the following

```
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=bowler,y=runsConceded)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=bowler,y=wicketKind,fill=wicketPlayerOut)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

 barchart(wicketPlayerOut~runsConceded|bowler,data=d)
```

Is it possible to capture all the columns either in a single plot
    with (bowler,wicketKind,wicketPlayerOut) vs max(runsConceded)

or in multiple plots for different bowlers with wicketKind,wicketPlayerOut and max(runsConceded)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your question 1st and make it a reproducible example, which includes a `dput` of your data, the necessary `library` calls, adding missing brackets (e.g. `geom_bar(stat="identity"`) and replacing missing data sets (e.g. `f` by `d`?).

Comment: Very difficult to understand your question. Cant understand what is a,d and f. Please add reproducible code.

Comment: If we had a reproducible example there would be something to work on, so here's a pseudo solution. You can use one column for `x`, one column for say color and a third column in `facet_wrap(~ ...)`. `runsConceded` would be on your y axis.

Comment: @Roman - That is all there is to it. The dataframe needs to be plotted, if possible, with all 4 columns. I need 2 plots as included in the post.  Not sure if it is possible to have 3 columns and each bowler as a separate plot.

Comment: @Roman - I used the facet as you suggested. I am getting a plot I intend, though it is not entirely correct. I will fix. You can answer the question and I will accept. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different mappings to get the desired plot. Try (within `aes`) `x`, `y`, `color` and a geom called [`facet_wrap()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html).